# Connect to sql server management studio with specific database name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want connect to sql server with username and password, but in this server I have over of 100 databases.

1.How can I connect to sql server and see just databases that I have owner access(filter on databases with I access them) ?

2.How can I connect to sql server with specific database name (1 of 100 database name), for example : Northwind Db.

Answer (score 4):

2/ Create a bat file with the following line of code:

```
ssms -S YourServerNameOrIP -d YourDbName -U UserName -P Password
```

or just run it in cmd

Comment: I want connect to server in sql server management studio. For example in servername textbox : 10.4.10.50\sql2008r2, NorthWind & in login textbox : sa & in password textbox : 123

Comment: I want filter database list, How can I it with your bat file ?

Answer (score 0):

1/ By default, all databases can be seen by any user. In order to revoke the permission to view all databases for the connected user use this:

```
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO <login>;
```